# Is there a way to tell if a user clicked on my google ad?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Google allows you to specify the order id when log a conversion. However, it doesn't link that order to the actual conversion data. It only uses it to avoid duplicates. So in other words, I can't match conversions to orders. I can only see that there has been X USD worth of connversions.

Instead of trying to set up Google Analytics to somehow measure this, it would be a lot easier if I could simply check if the user has in fact clicked on my advert when they submit the order. Then I can track conversions myself and no need to rely on Google. Which gives me a lot more control too.

So when a user places an order, and the conversion logic is kicked off, is there a way to decipher google's cookies so as to know the user clicked on my advert? For example, I clicked on my own advert and now it would be great if I could get the cookie like so:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['ga-advert-triggered'])) 
{
     // do stuff
}
```

But I dont think Google would make it that easy? Or do they?

Alternatively, is there perhaps a way I can ask Google if the current user has triggered my advert? Maybe their api has a javascript function. Something like:

```
if (GA.hasTriggeredAdverts()) {
     // do stuff
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options.

1. Add a query parameter to the URL in the ad's link. If the ad leads now to `http://example.com/myproduct.php` change it to (e.g.) `http://example.com/myproduct.php?from=googlead`. In the PHP code you check if `$_GET['from'] == "googlead"` and set a cookie or session variable.
2. Make the ad point to a redirect page. For example, the ad sends the user to `http://example.com/from_google_ad.php` which sets the cookie or session variable and then redirects to `http://example.com/myproduct.php`. Note that the redirect page must be on the same domain or Google will reject the ad.

Comment: Thats brilliant. Cant believe I didnt think of that. Thanks!